# Add mysql query item to php code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using below code to run a lightbox function. It works fine but I need to change the last line of - `lightbox_display('properties/593/', 'lightbox[gallery]');` to use $propertyimagefolder instead of 593. I tried `lightbox_display('properties/$propertyimagefolder/', 'lightbox[gallery]');` but no luck. Can anyone help with this?

```
$propertyimagefolder = $row['Reference_No'];

    function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel){
        $image_dir = $dir_to_search;
        $dir_to_search = scandir($dir_to_search);
        $image_exts = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $excluded_filename = '_t';

            foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
            $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
            $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
            $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
            $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
                if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false){

echo "<a href='../../".$image_dir.$image_file."' rel='".$rel."'><img src='../../".$image_dir.$filename.".".$filetype."' alt='".$filename."' width='100' height='80' title=''/></a>"."\n";

                }
            }
    }

    lightbox_display('properties/593/', 'lightbox[gallery]');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not process strings in single quotes for variables. Just replace with double quotes:

`lightbox_display("properties/$propertyimagefolder/", 'lightbox[gallery]');`

Or concatenate the variable and strings:

`lightbox_display('properties/' . $propertyimagefolder . '/', 'lightbox[gallery]');`